Use Import and Require to import JSON impact on the construction time of Webpack, vue cli5
I have a repo that built by vue/cli5 for vue3. I also use vue-i18n here. The main.
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import i18n from "./locales";
const app = createApp(App);
app.use(store);
app.use(router);
app.use(i18n);
app.mount("#app");
export default app;

the locales/index.ts is:
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import en from "./en.json";
import id from "./id.json";

const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    locale: process.env.VUE_APP_LANG, // set locale
    messages: {
        en,
        id,
    },
});

export default i18n;

There is hundreds of pages use i18n. Some of use it like
import i18n from "@/locales";
const { t } = i18n.global;

or
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
const { t } = useI18n;

When i run npm run build. It takes 180s and its really slow. But I change the locales/index.ts to:
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";

type LangMessages = Record<string, string>;
const lang = process.env.VUE_APP_LANG;
const langJsonMap: Record<string, string> = {
    en: "en",
    id: "id",
};

const json = require(`./${langJsonMap[lang]}.json`) as LangMessages;
const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    locale: process.env.VUE_APP_LANG, // set locale
    messages: {
        [process.env.VUE_APP_LANG]: json,
    },
});

export default i18n;

then i run npm run build again, it only takes 40s. What's the difference between import and require? And how does it affect the construction time? How do I track the time it consumes or how to compare it intuitively?
I have tried to use a custom plugin and obtain the JSON parsing time through hooks, but it consumes little time. maybe my useage is wrong.
thank you!!!

the json file is huge, almost 10000 lines.

I use ts in this repo. And configure tsconfig.json resolveJsonModule true
then the json module will be checked by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin, it takes a long time.
so change it to false, and add json declaration.
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "resolveJsonModule": false,
    }
}

declare global {
    declare module "*.json" {
        const value: any;
        export default value;
    }
}

it solved.

this is not an anwer. Please remove it and add it as a comment or an edit to your question.
